# UTF-8 encoding problem with flash mysql and php

Tags: flash, php

I am programming an on-line game using Flash. I am connecting my flash8 movie with MySQL database through PHP. I am doing very good in that, and I have everything working fine.

The problems come when I am trying to insert (Using the INSERT SQL func) data to the database that are non-english. In other words, UTF-8 data.

I red a lot of articls about that stuff and found and apply the fallowing:
1. In PHP4, you need to tell the PHP to use UTF-8 when using the xml_parser_crater() func, however, in PHP5 that is done automatically. Even though I told PHP5 to use the UTF-8 when calling the func.

1. Adding the  header to the XML sent to PHP from flash.
2. Force the FLASH to use UTF-8 encoding in the preference options.
3. Set the encoding in MySQL to UTF-8 (utf8_unicode_ci with InnoDB engine). I can read and insert the other language data correctly in the phpadmin as well.

I did all that in my coding, and still I can't insert such data.

one more strange thing is that, when I use the same link, that the FLASH using, with the XML, that the FLASH creating, on the browser (google chrome), I got the data inserted right in the database!!!!!

I am about to get crazy about that stuff, What am I missing? What causes the problem?

Comment: What is your collation set to in the mysql table you are trying to insert into?

Comment: utf8_unicode_ci for the entier database and fields. And I am using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: Could you post an example what gets inserted into the DB (when sent from flash) and what you were sending originally?

Comment: Also: Use a tool like Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to debug what flash sends to the server.

Comment: well, this is an example of what flash is sending (http://localhost/Asmsam/SaveCity.php?XXX=?<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><worlds><wname>ارض الحياة</wname><wdisc>منطقة غنية بالمواقع الطعام</wdisc></worlds>) When I use this excatly the same in the browser, the data is inserted correctly - with correct encoding- but when the FLASH send it, the PHP code just stoped and can't insert anything to the database!

Comment: I am new to web programming, So, I don't now much about how to use FireBuge thing. So, if you please tell me how to use it with FLASH (I am using the SendAndLoad() method in flash, it seems data is not sent to the browser because I did not see any thing on the firebug windows!)

Comment: In Firebug there's the "Net" tab. You should see all the requests there. Maybe you're just sending the stuff to a wrong address or you didn't encode/decode things properly.

Comment: What is your default PHP encoding displayed by phpinfo(); ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ditch the `mysql_*` functions and switch to something better like `mysqli_*` or PDO. See http://maurus.net/weblog/2006/07/28/typo3-php-mysql-connections-and-unicode/

Answer (score 0):

Right after the call to mysql_connect/mysql_select_db execute this:

```
mysql_query('set character set utf8');
```

to tell the PHP-MySQL driver to use UTF-8

Comment: I did that, but I still facing the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Escape your data with [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)